# Docker - passing arguments - syntax issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I would like to know what syntax should I use to `echo` an ARG that is passed to docker.

I would also like to know the syntax in order to pass that ARG to powershell command. Here is my attempt:

In my dockerfile, I define an ARG:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ARG web_connection_string

RUN echo " $web_connection_string."

ADD ./setup.ps1 /setup.ps1
RUN powershell -NoProfile -File C:\setup.ps1 -websiteDir "C:/inetpub/wwwroot" -webConnectionString $web_connection_string
```

setup.ps1 looks like this:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$websiteDir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$webConnectionString      
);

$sb = New-Object System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder
$sb.set_ConnectionString($webConnectionString)

[xml]$config = Get-Content "$pathToWebConfig"
$config.configuration.connectionStrings.GetElementsByTagName("add") `
    | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'SiteSqlServer' } `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.connectionString = $sb.ConnectionString; }
$config.Save("$websiteDir/web.config")
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "dnn-site"
    build: 
      context: .\
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:                                                                      
        web_connection_string: 'Server=db;Database=${dnn_database_name};User ID=${dnn_database_user_name};Password=${dnn_database_user_password};'
```

The values you see here using $() syntax are in an ".env" file in the same directory as my docker-compose.yml from where I am running `docker-compose` commands. `docker-compose` substitutes those values.

When I `docker-compose up` I see this output:

In the output I see:

```
Step 1/13 : FROM microsoft/aspnet
 ---> dc3f4d701ead
Step 2/13 : ARG web_connection_string
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 79fea0b34b8d
Step 3/13 : RUN echo " $web_connection_string."
 ---> Running in 7a3552cedc92
.
```

Note that $web_connection_string is seemingly empty. Is this due to the way I am echoing it? OR has it been supplied empty (i.e my docker-compose.yml is wrong?)

Also the way I am passing the value as a param to the setup.ps1 script - is that the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting some more.
It seems ARG's passed in to Docker build, are accessed in powershell using:

```
$Env:ARGNAME
```

For example:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ARG web_connection_string

RUN echo " $Env:web_connection_string."
```

So to call a powershell script and pass one as an argument:

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile -File C:\setup.ps1 -myparameter $Env:web_connection_string
```

Note this only seems to work for ARG's. If you are using ENV values like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ENV web_connection_string
```

And you are parsing the relevent environment values using the `environment` section of docker-compose.yml

```
web: 
    image: "dnn-web"
    build: 
      context: .\
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    environment:
        web_connection_string: '${some_foo_from_dot_env_file}'
```

Then the following doesn't seem to work, as it only seems to work for ARG values.

RUN echo " $Env:web_connection_string."

outputs

> .

Comment: None of that works at all. Cannot access build args via $Env:BuildArgName.  ENV doesn't work either.